# Accessing private wordpress blog rss feed from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordpress, rss

I am working on an ASP.NET page that contains an XML reader that reads from a wordpress rss feed, formats the posts, and pastes it on the secure site. How can I secure the wordpress blog feed so that no one can access it but the ASP.NET app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this post in the future, I ended up using the JoeBlogs c# wrapper for the XML-RPC wordpress plugin. Two things to note: - when I downloaded the dll, there was an error in the parameter type used in getrecentposts - also, make sure the url links to the xml-rpc.php page of your wordpress blog (if you're using a free hosted version)